# How do I automatically generate image styles?

Tags: 8, media

How do I automatically generate different image styles in Drupal 8, for existing images?

For example, I have about 10K images in field_image field. I would like to generate thumbnails using my thumbnail image style for those images.

Comment: Image derivatives will be automatically generated once requested and not-yet existing.

Comment: I never mentioned in the question, that I wanted to do it programmatically!! This can be achieved with [Image Style Warmer](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_style_warmer) which is available for D8. Worked perfectly for me! This might help other people, who are trying to find a solution.

Comment: You should add that as answer to the other question.

Answer (score 12):

Image derivatives will be automatically generated once requested and not-yet existing.

But if you are asking how to programmatically create image derivatives checkout [`ImageStyle::createDerivative`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Entity%21ImageStyle.php/function/ImageStyle%3A%3AcreateDerivative/8.2.x).

Here's a sample snippet were I did exactly that:

```
$field_name = 'field_my_image';
$image_style_name = 'my_image_style';
$image = [];

// Get the original image URI.
$original_image = $node->{$field_name}->entity->getFileUri();

// Load the image style.
$style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('image_style')
  ->load($image_style_name);

// Get the styled image derivative.
$destination = $style->buildUri($original_image);

// If the derivative doesn't exist yet (as the image style may have been
// added post launch), create it.
if (!file_exists($destination)) {
  $style->createDerivative($original_image, $destination);
}

// Do whatever else you need to do.
$image['url'] = file_url_transform_relative($style->buildUrl($original_image));
$properties = $node->{$field_name}->first()->getValue();
$image['alt'] = $properties['alt'];
$image['title'] = $properties['title'];
```